# Are interpolation methods the same in all software, produce the same result ( with same settings) or does it differ from software to software?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, software-recommendations, interpolation

I was wondering if interpolation algorithm has been changed? produce the same result in all software so it is not software based. This would be if the settings are exactly the same of course.

Let's say that I use two different software to produce a nearest neighbor interpolation with the same data. Will it be the same result or is the algorithm a bit different for every software?

Comment: In theory, the algorithm is the same, but the implementations are of course different. Unfortunately, this can't be answered without undertaking a study that could take a thousand hours, evaluating dozens of packages for scores of algorithms for dozens of data alignment cases.

Comment: Okej, thank you for the answer!

Comment: For each specific algorithm, you can find details about how it's implemented in each software's technical documentation. (In case you want to undertake the "thousand hour study" that Vince mentioned.)

Comment: For now I think I will skip that. But it would be interesting to see how it's implemented in different software.